# How do i stop my Link from being tabbable?

Tags: reactjs

my code is

```
 <Link to="/Cleaning_Search" className={Style.link}><Button className="button"> 
    
   <h2> Cleaning</h2>
</Button>
</Link> 




 import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
```

When I press the tab button it iterates though the normal icons, but it both tabs through the button and the Link that is held over the tab.

What is the solution to stop this?

Comment: I guess a bigger issue/question is, why is there a button inside a link? I suspect you still want the link to be interactable, you could try setting a `tabIndex="-1"` on the button so it can't be keyboard tabbed to.

Comment: Is there a problem with having the button inside the link? It is more just a shortcut for css. I also forgot how to make a button go to the link. 

I'm aware of the index thing, i just want the button to be the only tabbable option.

Comment: ah sorry, i didnt realise that tabIndex="-1" actually removes tabbableness, i thought it added it.

Comment: "Is there a problem?", yes, potentially. If the click event from the button doesn't bubble/propagate to the link then the link stops working. The button also doesn't provide the same accessibility cues he link does. If a user hovers over the button they don't see the same link hints. If you want the link to be skippable and tab to the button then users using screen readers also won't have the link announced. If you want a link that looks like a button then the right thing to do is to style the link.